# How set click on each word of TextView which is change dynamically?

Tags: java, android

I making an app in  which `TextView` use a `setText` from server.
So the string getting from server is dynamically change by user.
Now I want to make all words clickable from `TextView`.

For example:

```
TextView return the text(string) is : cricket football hockey ...etc(whatever).
```

For this, I want to make each word clickable send the user to other activity for users like hashTag fashion in social media.

```
     SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
                String[] words = tag.split(" ");
                for(final String word: words)
                {
                    builder.append(word).setSpan(new ClickableSpan()
                    {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(@NonNull View view)
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(ClickPostEdit.this, word, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                                // optional - for styling the specific text
            /*@Override
            public void updateDrawState(@NonNull TextPaint textPaint) {
                textPaint.setColor(textPaint.linkColor);    // you can use custom color
                textPaint.setUnderlineText(false);    // this remove the underline
            }*/
            }, builder.length() - word.length(), word.length(), 1);

                }
                EditPostTag.setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
                EditPostTag.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append [ClickableSpans](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan) to a [SpannbleStringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html).

You can iterate through your list of words, append each word to the builder and attach a ClickableSpan to it:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
for(String word: words) {
    builder
            .append(word)
            .setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull View view) {
                    // on click
                }

                // optional - for styling the specific text
                /*@Override
                public void updateDrawState(@NonNull TextPaint textPaint) {
                    textPaint.setColor(textPaint.linkColor);    // you can use custom color
                    textPaint.setUnderlineText(false);    // this remove the underline
                }*/
            }, builder.length() - word.length(), builder.length(), 0);

}
```

To set this Spannable to a TextView, use:

```
textView.setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Taken from [this](https://medium.com/viithiisys/android-multiple-click-actions-on-single-textview-c5fec71b6e25) post.

I hope you find my answer helpful!

Results:
Added ", " after each word

[image: Added ", " after each word]

Comment: i use textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

Comment: My original answer worked only after i added `textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`

Comment: Made a mistake, in `setSpan(ClickableSpan(){...},  builder.length() - word.length(),` **builder.length()**  `, 0);`. This is working for me with list of strings, and each of them is clickable.

Comment: dont know but happing with me that not work let me try again

Comment: can you please add log in on click

Comment: Modify into what? Why didn't you use SpannableStringBuilder?

Comment: SpannableStringBuilder i alredy used

Comment: oh sorry bro your string like cricket, football, hockey and my string like cricket football hockey

Comment: you didn't use `textView.setText(ss,` **TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)**;

Comment: wait what ,,ss for what ?

Comment: That's better. now you only need to change the indexes when setting the spanned to: `setSpan(ClickableSpan(){...}, builder.length() - word.length(), builder.length() , 0);` as i commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520906/how-set-click-on-each-word-of-textview-which-is-change-dynamically/#comment97749733_55520993) and also change in my answer

Comment: i ask this many people to this , but they always send me to developer.android.com , in where i really cant understand

Comment: It's not the coding itself but more of knowing what to search online. You can be sure that someone already asked something similar enough that may help your situation. I only google searched "textview click android", then found [the mentioned](https://medium.com/viithiisys/android-multiple-click-actions-on-single-textview-c5fec71b6e25) medium article. I knew Spannable is for formatting text in textViews so this could be a good solution. All you need to do is search, it's an acquired skill :)

Comment: thanx once again brother and keep in touch

Comment: I lost My space in TextView by split by " "
So how set space or comma beween word in spannable builder

Comment: Just do `builder.append(" ")` in the main loop, after handling each word